# Is there an engine for Duck Chess?

Tags: engines, chess-variants

Is there a chess engine for the chess variant Duck Chess? If not, is there a known plan of development of such an engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Edit on 18.01.2023:

Fairy-Stockfish released the duck-chess variant. You can reach it from [their github](https://github.com/ianfab/Fairy-Stockfish).

Answer (score 2):

I also investigated this topic and I created an experimental engine of my own: https://github.com/OndrejKincl/DuckChess.jl

From this experience, I would say it will not be very difficult to prune possible duck moves but main obstacle is that there is currently not much theory or data to test against.

Answer (score 2):

## AI on pychess.org

[pychess.org](https://www.pychess.org/) added Duck Chess as a variant on [2022-12-26](https://www.pychess.org/news/Duck_Chess), and also included an AI. You can play against it by choosing `PLAY WITH AI` on the main page, then selecting the `DUCK` variant.

[image: Duck Chess]

Comment: Do you know which engine it uses? or is it just a simple AI?

Comment: @Minot No clue, just saw it on IM Rosens stream yesterday and then remembered this question.

Comment: It is Fairy-Stockfish, or more precisely exactly using the branch the accepted answer is pointing to as well.

Answer (score 2):

On this [link](https://talkchess.com/forum3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=80829&p=939744&hilit=duck#p939744) you can find developpers programming a Duck Chess engine, available [here](http://hgm.nubati.net/Duck2.zip). This engine is named Quack.